# Setting the enumi counter under parametrized enumitem

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, enumitem

This is a variation on two previously asked questions: [Setting the enumi counter under custom enumeration with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214732/setting-the-enumi-counter-under-custom-enumeration-with-enumitem) and [Looking for a numbered List, with parameter, custom label and custom reference text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21747/looking-for-a-numbered-list-with-parameter-custom-label-and-custom-reference-t/21750#21750).

The output of the code below is

(1) A

(2) B

(3) C

(U1) A

(U2) B

(U1) C

and I would like the last line to be

(U3) C

How should I modify the environment "test" to keep the parameter, the right references, but be able to modify the counter easily?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\parameter{}
\newenvironment{test}[1]
{\renewcommand\parameter{#1}\begin{Mylist}}{\end{Mylist}}

\newlist{Mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Mylist]{label=(\req*), ref=\arabic*}

\newcommand{\req}[1]{\expandafter\inreq\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\inreq}[1]{\parameter \number#1}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\req}{\inreq}{99}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*]
  \item A 
  \item B
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{test}{U}
    \item A
    \item B
\end{test}
\begin{test}{U} % What should replace [resume*] here ?
    \item C
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your `test` environment as

```
\newenvironment{test}[2][]
{\begin{enumerate}[series=tests,label=(#2\arabic*),#1]}
{\end{enumerate}}
```

and resume it using `resume=tests`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{test}[2][]
{\begin{enumerate}[series=tests,label=(#2\arabic*),#1]}
{\end{enumerate}}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*]
  \item A
  \item B
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{test}{U}
    \item A
    \item B
\end{test}
\begin{test}[resume=tests]{U}
    \item C
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a more pragmatic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{mO{}}
 {\enumerate[label=(#1\arabic*),ref=\arabic*,#2]}
 {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*]
  \item A
  \item B
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{test}{U}
    \item A
    \item B
\end{test}
\begin{test}{U}[resume*]
    \item C
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel sorry not to be able to mark both answers as accepted.